# How to get Django and ReactJS to work together?

Tags: django, reactjs

<sup>New to Django and even newer to ReactJS. I have been looking into AngularJS and ReactJS, but decided on ReactJS. It seemed like it was edging out AngularJS as far as popularity despite AngularJS having more of a market share, and ReactJS is said to be quicker to pickup.</sup>

<sup>All that junk aside, I started taking a course on Udemy and after a few videos it seemed important to see how well it integrates with Django. That is when I inevitably hit a wall just getting it up and running, what kind of documentation is out there so that I am not spinning my wheels for several hours and nights.</sup>

There really isn't any comprehensive tutorials, or `pip` packages, I came across. The few I came across didn't work or were dated, `pyreact` for example.

One thought I had was just to treat ReactJS completely separate, but keeping into consideration the classes and IDs I want the ReactJS components to render in. After the separate ReactJS components are compiled into a single ES5 file, just import that single file into the Django template.

I think that will quickly breakdown when I get to rendering from Django models although the Django Rest Framework sounds like it is involved. Not even far enough to see how Redux affects all of this.

Does anyone have a clear way they are using Django and ReactJS?

<sup>At any rate, the documentation and tutorials are plentiful for AngularJS and Django, so it is tempting to just go that route to get started with any front-end framework... Not the best reason.</sup>

Comment: I had similar curiosities, and setup an [example](https://github.com/danwild/react-webpack-django) app for react+webpack+django - the repo also links to some related tools and articles which might be useful.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

I don't have experience with Django but the concepts from front-end to back-end and front-end framework to framework are the same.

1. **React will consume your [Django REST API](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/)**. Front-ends and back-ends aren't connected in any way. React will make HTTP requests to your REST API in order to fetch and set data.
2. React, with the help of **Webpack (module bundler) & Babel (transpiler)**, will bundle and transpile your Javascript into single or multiple files that will be placed in the entry HTML page. **Learn Webpack, Babel, Javascript and React and Redux (a state container)**. I *believe* you won't use Django templating but instead allow React to render the front-end.
3. As this page is rendered, React will consume the API to fetch data so React can render it. Your understanding of **HTTP requests, Javascript (ES6), Promises, Middleware and React** is essential here.

Here are a few things I've found on the web that *should* help (based on a quick Google search):

- [Django and React API Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CxjJ7siCK44)
- [Setting up Django with React](https://web.archive.org/web/20171207032005/http://geezhawk.github.io/using-react-with-django-rest-framework) (replaced broken link with archive.org link)
- Search for other resources using the bolded terms above. Try "Django React Webpack" first.

Hope this steers you in the right direction! Good luck! Hopefully others who specialize in Django can add to my response.

Comment: I will check out the YouTube tutorial. I did go through both of those tutorials previously. Article 1 didn't work although I followed it closely. (Copied and pasted most of the code). That is on an existing project, but I'll try a new one. Article 2 used deprecated packages and hadn't been updated recently. Anyway, reading more about AngularJS and Django it sounds like the Django REST API is still used. I guess I was looking for a solution without adding that dimension, but it sounds like it is unavoidable.

Comment: Ok I updated my answer a bit by taking out the outdated article. It's over 2 years old so it definitely needed to be removed. Does the numbered bullets help? What are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: After trying the second link several more times on existing projects and brand new projects, I got them at least talking. The line `{% render_bundle 'main' %}` is wrong and should be `{% render_bundle "main" %}`.

Comment: thanks for the last comment it threw error cant render main from main

Comment: The second link is not working. Please update the link.

Comment: I would replace that dead 2nd link w/ this article, i followed this and it mostly works..  https://medium.com/labcodes/configuring-django-with-react-4c599d1eae63

Answer (score 46):

I feel your pain as I, too, am starting out to get Django and React.js working together. Did a couple of Django projects, and I think, React.js is a great match for Django. However, it can be intimidating to get started. We are standing on the shoulders of giants here ;)

Here's how I think, it all works together (big picture, please someone correct me if I'm wrong).

- Django and its database (I prefer Postgres) on one side (backend)
- Django Rest-framework providing the interface to the outside world (i.e. Mobile Apps and React and such)
- Reactjs, Nodejs, Webpack, Redux (or maybe MobX?) on the other side (frontend)

Communication between Django and 'the frontend' is done via the Rest framework. Make sure you get your authorization and permissions for the Rest framework in place.

I found a good boiler template for exactly this scenario and it works out of the box. Just follow the readme https://github.com/scottwoodall/django-react-template and once you are done, you have a pretty nice Django Reactjs project running.
By no means this is meant for production, but rather as a way for you to dig in and see how things are connected and working!

One tiny change I'd like to suggest is this:
Follow the setup instructions BUT before you get to the 2nd step to setup the backend (Django here https://github.com/scottwoodall/django-react-template/blob/master/backend/README.md), change the requirements file for the setup.

You'll find the file in your project at     /backend/requirements/common.pip
Replace its content with this

```
appdirs==1.4.0
Django==1.10.5
django-autofixture==0.12.0
django-extensions==1.6.1
django-filter==1.0.1
djangorestframework==3.5.3
psycopg2==2.6.1
```

this gets you the latest stable version for Django and its Rest framework.

I hope that helps.

Comment: A year later, I switched to VUE.js (https://vuejs.org/). I made it work with the Django templates and it will communicate to the database via the Django Rest Framework.
It is fast and light (~20kb)

Answer (score 40):

Hoping to provide a more nuanced answer than any of the ones here, especially as some things have changed since this was originally asked ~4 years ago, and because many of the top-voted answers claiming that you have to set this up as two separate applications are not accurate.

You have two primary architecture options:

1. A completely decoupled client/server approach using something like [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) and [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)
2. A hybrid architecture where you set up a React build pipeline (likely using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)) and then include the compiled files as static files in your Django templates.

These might look something like this:

Option 1 (Client/Server Architecture):

[image: Client / Server Architecture]

Option 2 (Hybrid Architecture):

[image: Hybrid Architecture]

The decision between these two will depend on your / your team's experience, as well as the complexity of your UI. The first option is good if you have a lot of JS experience, want to keep your front-end / back-end developers separate, or want to write *your entire application as a React single-page-app*. The second option is generally better if you are more familiar with Django and *want to move quickly while also using React for some parts of your app*. I find it's a particularly good fit for full-stack solo-developers.

There is a lot more information in the series "[Modern JavaScript for Django Developers](https://www.saaspegasus.com/guides/modern-javascript-for-django-developers/)", including [choosing your architecture](https://www.saaspegasus.com/guides/modern-javascript-for-django-developers/client-server-architectures/), [integrating your JS build into a Django project](https://www.saaspegasus.com/guides/modern-javascript-for-django-developers/integrating-javascript-pipeline/) and [building a single-page React app](https://www.saaspegasus.com/guides/modern-javascript-for-django-developers/integrating-django-react/).

Full disclosure, I'm the author of that series.

Comment: I followed best I could but when I try to run it, I get an error regarding the url settings. specifically, it doesn't know `TemplateViews` in the line `path('hello-webpack/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='hello_webpack.html'))`

Comment: @Gandora did you import the class? You can find more details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/

Comment: Will django forms and context processors still work with option 2?

Comment: Oh actually just saw your articles. Good info in there!

Answer (score 19):

As others answered you, if you are creating a new project, you can separate frontend and backend and use any django rest plugin to create rest api for your frontend application. This is in the ideal world.

If you have a project with the django templating already in place, then you must load your react dom render in the page you want to load the application. In my case I had already *django-pipeline* and I just added the browserify extension. (https://github.com/j0hnsmith/django-pipeline-browserify)

As in the example, I loaded the app using django-pipeline:

```
PIPELINE = {
    # ...
    'javascript':{
        'browserify': {
            'source_filenames' : (
                'js/entry-point.browserify.js',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'js/entry-point.js',
        },
    }
}
```

Your "*entry-point.browserify.js*" can be an ES6 file that loads your react app in the template:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/app.js';
import "babel-polyfill";

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import reducers from './reducers/index.js';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
  promise
)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App/>
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('my-react-app')
);
```

In your django template, you can now load your app easily:

```
{% load pipeline %}

{% comment %} 
`browserify` is a PIPELINE key setup in the settings for django 
 pipeline. See the example above
{% endcomment %}

{% javascript 'browserify' %}

{% comment %} 
the app will be loaded here thanks to the entry point you created 
in PIPELINE settings. The key is the `entry-point.browserify.js` 
responsable to inject with ReactDOM.render() you react app in the div 
below
{% endcomment %}
<div id="my-react-app"></div>
```

The advantage of using django-pipeline is that statics get processed during the `collectstatic`.

Answer (score 18):

The first approach is building separate Django and React apps. Django will be responsible for serving the API built using Django REST framework and React will consume these APIs using the Axios client or the browser's fetch API. **You'll need to have two servers, both in development and production, one for Django(REST API) and the other for React (to serve static files)**.

The second approach is different **the frontend and backend apps will be coupled**. Basically you'll use Django to both serve the React frontend and to expose the REST API. So you'll need to integrate React and Webpack with Django, these are the steps that you can follow to do that

First generate your Django project then inside this project directory generate your React application using the React CLI

For Django project install  **django-webpack-loader** with pip:

```
pip install django-webpack-loader
```

Next add the app to installed apps and configure it in `settings.py` by adding the following object

```
WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
            'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': '',
            'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats.json'),
        }
}
```

Then add a Django template that will be used to mount the React application and will be served by Django

```
{ % load render_bundle from webpack_loader % }

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Django + React </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
     This is where React will be mounted
    </div>
    { % render_bundle 'main' % }
  </body>
</html>
```

Then add an URL in `urls.py` to serve this template

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="main.html")),

]
```

If you start both the Django and React servers at this point you'll get a Django error saying the `webpack-stats.json` doesn't exist. So next you need to make your React application able to generate the stats file.

Go ahead and navigate inside your React app then install `webpack-bundle-tracker`

```
npm install webpack-bundle-tracker --save
```

Then eject your Webpack configuration and go to `config/webpack.config.dev.js` then add

```
var BundleTracker  = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');
//...

module.exports = {

    plugins: [
          new BundleTracker({path: "../", filename: 'webpack-stats.json'}),
    ]
}
```

This add *BundleTracker* plugin to Webpack and instruct it to generate `webpack-stats.json` in the parent folder.

Make sure also to do the same in `config/webpack.config.prod.js` for production.

Now if you re-run your React server the `webpack-stats.json` will be generated and Django will be able to consume it to find information about the Webpack bundles generated by React dev server.

There are some other things to. You can find more information from this [tutorial](https://www.techiediaries.com/django-react-rest/).

Comment: Do you need webpack-dev-server running in a coupled approach? Because in the tutorial he's running it. From my understanding it needs to be run because it is used by django to keep the bundles updated. Is this right? If it is how would this work in production, i.e. would I still need two servers?

Comment: In development you'll need both Django dev server and React/Webpack dev server running. In production you just need one server (Django) running because Django will take care of serving the built files generated by `npm run build`

Comment: Thanks for clarification.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the First approach? From what I understand, it would contain an `express` server running which will serve React static JS files and that JS files would do an ajax request to fetch data from the Django server. The browser first hits the `express` server, it does not have any idea about the Django one. Am I correct? Is something like Server side rendering doable with the this approach?

Comment: You can simply use a static host and a CDN for your static files. For example you can use GitHub Pages to host the React application & CloudFlare as a CDN. For server side rendering you need another setup like using an Express server  BUT there are also static hosting services that offer server side rendering like Netlify.

Comment: Will django forms and context processors still work/

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer lead me to believe that decoupling Django backend and React Frontend is the right way to go no matter what. In fact there are approaches in which React and Django are coupled, which may be better suited in particular situations.

[This tutorial](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/drf/) well explains this. In particular:

> I see the following patterns (which are common to almost every web framework):
>
> -React in its own “frontend” Django app: load a single HTML template and let React manage the frontend (difficulty: medium)
>
> -Django REST as a standalone API + React as a standalone SPA (difficulty: hard, it involves JWT for authentication)
>
> -Mix and match: mini React apps inside Django templates (difficulty: simple)

Comment: I think that the KISS solution is te best, mix and match.

Answer (score 13):

A note for anyone who is coming from a backend or Django based role and trying to work with ReactJS: No one manages to setup ReactJS enviroment successfully in the first try :)

There is a blog from Owais Lone which is available from http://owaislone.org/blog/webpack-plus-reactjs-and-django/ ; however syntax on Webpack configuration is way out of date.

I suggest you follow the steps mentioned in the blog and replace the webpack configuration file with the content below. However if you're new to both Django and React, chew one at a time because of the learning curve you will probably get frustrated.

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: './static/assets/js/index',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./static/assets/bundles/'),
        filename: '[name]-[hash].js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'})
    ],

 module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },


  resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a couple of years late, but I'm putting it out there for the next person on this journey.

GraphQL has been helpful and way easier compared to DjangoRESTFramework. It is also more flexible in terms of the responses you get. You get what you ask for and don't have to filter through the response to get what you want.

You can use Graphene Django on the server side and React+Apollo/Relay... You can look into it as that is not your question.

Comment: Graphene and React + Apollo is an excellent stack! Slightly more Python to write than DRF, but an enormous reduction in JS code, especially since Apollo kills the need for redux.

Answer (score 0):

Create reactapp in django projects root directory containing manage.py folder.
Then configure the settings files accordingly.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ....
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/build'),],
        ....
    },
]
```

..

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/build/static'),
]
```