# Passing props to bundle.js - React and Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

Am a bit stuck and need some help on this. I have followed the Spring Boot and React Tutorial, linked - http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/ and have successfully managed to integrate Spring Boot and React. However I have a requirement now wherein I need to pass parameters to the React component from my html page to the React component (details like userId, URLs etc)? How can I pass parameters to the pre-compiled bundle.js and in turn to the  react component? This is how my script tag in index.html looks currently.

```
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="built/index.bundle.js"></script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry should have done some more googling before posting the query. Posting an answer in case someone stumbles upon the same issue.

Chris Unsell's answer over here [How to pass props from template to react root node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43847077/how-to-pass-props-from-template-to-react-root-node) helped me figure it out.