# How to configure Django Rest Framework + React

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have an application backend in Django-rest-framework, and I have a reactjs app.

How can I do to they work together ? 
For development I open 2 terminals and run them separately. There is some way to make them work together ?

Also to deploy it to production I have no idea how I can do that.
I tried to look for some github project ready, but couldn't find anything

Thanks!

Comment: Pycharm will allow you to work on both at the same time.

Comment: I have to vote to close this question as too broad - how do you deploy multiple applications in production depends entirely on which of the many hosting solutions available you choose.

Comment: How do you run a reactjs app in a terminal?

Comment: If you don't want to help, don't answer nothing @trixn

Comment: @rafalmp if I knew how to get them to work together, I could deploy it

Comment: I want to help you thinking about what is actually running in your terminal because it's not react. react is a front-end rendering framework that runs in the browser (except for server side rendering). Your question is so basic that i doubt that you dealt with any of those technologies a little bit closer. There are plenty of tutorials dealing with exactly that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Django and ReactJS to work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867055/how-to-get-django-and-reactjs-to-work-together)

Answer (score 1):

You should add CORS support to django if you developing on separate servers.
[Here the package for DRF](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/) it contains instructions how to setup CORS properly.
Here is what you can do on the production server
in the main urls:

```
# all your project urls
urlpatterns = [
   ... 
   url(r'^', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='index')
]
```

`TemplateView` at the end of urlpatterns will match for all requests which not matched by previous url patters. This view should serve a template with a wepback bundle.
Then you do collectstatic and point nginx static to static root as usual.
You could do the same on the develop environment if you want.
And don't forget to change root url for your backend api in React app:

```
let ROOT = '/api/'
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    ROOT = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For dev:
You can run both of them on two different shells. By default, your django rest api will be at 127.0.0.1:8000 and React will at 127.0.0.1:8081. I do not think there will be any issues for the two to communicate via the fetch api. Just make sure you have `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['127.0.0.1']` in your django's settings file.

For production:
It will work like any other mobile app or web app does! Host your your RESTful API on an application server (aws, heroku or whatever you choose) and create and host your React App separately. Use Javascript's fetch api to send requests to your django endpoints and use the json/xml response to render your views in React.