# Django REST API as backend and ReactJS as frontend integration

Tags: django, reactjs

I'm learning ReactJS and I already have experience with Django and DRF. My aim right now is to build a rather simple web application based on a Django backend and a ReactJS frontend. (Later on, when the web app is done, I'll tackle React Native).
I've been reading tons of documentation but nothing has sorted out the question:

> What is the best approach to integrate a Django backend with a ReactJS frontend?

Should I keep them separate and connect them or should I mount ReactJS inside the Django application? Which one is the best-suited approach, taking into account maintenance and further development?
Thank you very much! Any opinion/hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Django and ReactJS to work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867055/how-to-get-django-and-reactjs-to-work-together)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be make an app called `frontend` or anything you like in Django, then all of my React code will be placed inside that app. You will also need webpack to bundle your React code then with `collectstatic` command Django will collect all the static files so it could be served. You can find the tutorial [here](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/tutorial-api-django-rest-react/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My doubt is: in case I want to develop other frontend apps that uses the same backend (such as a mobile app with React Native), will the approach suggested still be ok? Or would it be better to completely separate backend and frontend?

Comment: @Giulia Sure ! REST API could be consume from anywhere, mobile apps or web apps it doesn't matter. The reason I choose to place the React code inside Django is because I can reduce from 2 repos to 1 repo only. And for some reason if you still want to separate them, it's completely fine.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason it seemed to me that separating them completely was better in terms of flexibility and future development, but from your answer I can see that's not the case. So I'll have React inside Django which is likely to be a little easier right now. Thank you very much!