# How to implement Django REST with React

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, shopify-app

How can I make react scripts properly served from Django?
I mean that I want that react will be served from Django view and not separately.

what is the best practice for gluing them up together?

I need it because I'm developing a Shopify app and in the installation process, the Shopify platform sends a request to my app and waiting for a response in some cases, and right now it's sending it to static react files which not responding as needed.

Comment: You can take the react build and serve it as a template from a django view.

Answer (score 3):

React will consume your Django REST API. Front-ends and back-ends aren't connected in any way. React will make HTTP requests to your REST API in order to fetch and set data.
Find more here
[How to get Django and ReactJS to work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867055/how-to-get-django-and-reactjs-to-work-together)

Comment: I built it this way in the beginning but my issue is that Shopify sending requests and expecting to redirect back. I'm using django-shopify-auth which doing this process and when I'm defining react static files as an app so these redirections not getting.