# What is the best way to integrate a react and django application?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am making a full stack website using react and django. I came across various ways to integrate them both. Having them both as two separate projects and interacting using API, or putting react in the django folder and calling the backend. Which method would be better and much easier? And can you also mention the pros and cons of each method.

Comment: There's a very similar question with much more discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867055/how-to-get-django-and-reactjs-to-work-together

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's actually quite easy, you just have to wrap your head around which part of your project handles which concern.

## The "project management" part of the question

### Having them in the same repo

This is a good idea for deployment, as you won't have problems of synchronization between the 2 code-bases, however, with increasing number of developers it can potentially lead to management problems, as you're have branches based on both backend and frontend things.

So to summarize:

- Easier to deploy, since it's a single code base
- Could lead to potential problematic management with scaling the development team
- Makes task that are "full-stack" easier to manage, as you have it in a single code-base
- Not so easy to split if you're aiming to scale separate "frontend" and "backend" teams

### Having them in different repos

In contrast, this makes it harder to deploy, but easier to separate the tasks. You have 2 separate projects to maintain, an "API" and a "front-end". Depending on the way you set this up, you can even serve your front-end project using a CDN, and this opens doors to some modern stacks, like serverless, or you can deploy on Vercel, which has a free plan. All-in-all this is usually a safer option for larger teams.

So to summarize:

- A bit harder to deploy, manage staging
- Easier task sub-splitting between the teams

## The "engineering" part of the question

In regards to the engineering part, React has to be "transpiled", which means that the browsers don't know how to "interpret" it. That means you'll have to pick one of various bundlers, but I can suggest a few popular ones:

- Webpack custom made config
- Create React App (comes with webpack)
- Parcel (0 config)
- Snowpack ( I've heard great things about this one, since it's `node_modules` "free"

Once you have this, you'll have a way to get "production" ready compiled javascript/css `assets` which you need to serve to your user. Depending on what you went with on the "project management" side of things, you can either serve the assets with one-click solutions, or a CDN, or in fact, merge your front-end project with the backend, and build your assets, and serve them with Django itself.

The choice depends on what you want to achieve, but to summarize:

- Serving with django - You'll only have a single server to handle everything, but that means if you plan your site to be globally available, you'll have think about the infrastructure
- Serving with one-click solutions or CDNs, and a separate API - Pick this if you plan to have a fast loading site everywhere in the world, makes it a bit easier to scale

All-in-all this is kinda a complex topic, but if you're just making a startup or a small project for yourself to play with, I suggest you go with simply serving everything with Django, and keeping everything in a single codebase!