# Connect Django and React

Tags: reactjs, django, integration

I have a react application built with dummy data that does stuff. This data is data that should be reached by making a request to my server. My React app is not connected to anything as of now I have to separate folders

1. My folder with my react application
2. My folder with my Django application

My Django application is built - small application that has CRUD features.

I want to integrate my React app with my Django application so that they work together. What would be the best way for doing this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Django and ReactJS to work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867055/how-to-get-django-and-reactjs-to-work-together)

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to :

in django:

- convert your django project to django rest framework project
- now you've got an API with URLs
- install corsheaders to allow communication with front end

in react:

- replace all local data with Async functions with http request with django API urls from before
- you'll need to install "Axios" for that purpose,it is best choice or stick with "fetch"
- use the data

all of these are just big titles, you'll need to dive into that

hers is a good friendly Todo project with Django/React,

```
https://github.com/Abdelazizkb/react-hooks-django-todo
```

Comment: Does it really have to be converted to a rest framework. I have a project I built following the guidelines from `https://www.saaspegasus.com/guides/modern-javascript-for-django-developers/client-server-architectures/` but although it worked for my app I was building following those guidelines I can't get it to work with mine exactly. Not sure if you might know if this is actually feasible?

Comment: Hi Michael - I'm the author of that series. It's certainly feasible. If you have any specific questions feel free to get in touch! My email is cory at saaspegasus dot com

Comment: Thank you Cory - I took you up on that offer.